# How can I delete a row just in my report (statistics) BUT not from my table

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a column, it's called IsDeleted and this column contains True/False. This means if employees have terminated it's True. If not, it's False and it works fine. But, when I run my query, it will show both those that have True and False. But I just want to show those that have False and hide/delete those that have true. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

My Query :

```
create function dbo.birthdate_from_cpr(@cpr varchar(10))
returns date
as
begin
  declare @year char(2) = substring(@cpr, 5, 2),
          @month char(2) = substring(@cpr, 3, 2),
          @day char(2) = substring(@cpr, 1, 2),
          @century char(2)



  if right(datepart(yy, getdate()), 2) < @year
    set @century = left(datepart(yy, getdate()) - 100, 2)
  else
    set @century = left(datepart(yy, getdate()), 2)


  return convert(date, @century + @year + @month + @day, 120)
end
go

select dbo.birthdate_from_cpr('1312761234'),
       dbo.birthdate_from_cpr('0101041234'),
       age = datediff(yy, dbo.birthdate_from_cpr('1312761234'), getdate())
```

Comment: Please post the full query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `where u.IsDeleted = 0` to your query after your `from` (which isn't shown in your code as posted).

```
select
  ...
from 
  ...
where u.IsDeleted = 0
  ...
```

Comment: tnx SqlZim , you right , i just can't believe myself . it was simple thing